# Cannot find string in variable using in_array function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to search the array $outcome for the string "**Destination host unreachable**" and it  doesn't work.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and was wondering if someone could lend a hand?

```
   $ip = 192.168.1.30

   $pingresult = exec("ping -n 1 $ip", $outcome, $status);

   if ($status == 0) 
       {                                        
           if(in_array("Destination host unreachable", $outcome))
               {
                   echo "Unreachable";
               }
           else
               {
                   echo "Alive";
               }   
       }
```

P.S. Please note I'm on a Windows machine so the exit status is different to Linux etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try.

```
if(array_search($outcome, "Destination host unreachable") !== false){
 echo 'not reachable';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using this. Although I do get 'expects a string, not an array' error. Nevertheless it seems to be working like that.

Comment: ohh ok. this function is for string thats why notworking for array.
try this it will work.

if(array_search($outcome, "Destination host unreachable") !== false){
 echo 'not reachable';
}

Answer (score 1):

`in_array` returns true on exact matches only. So, if there are additional characters on the line (including white space), it won't match. You may wish to loop through the array using preg_match.